# How to get only user defined classes in Python /PyQt5?

Tags: python, class, pyqt, pyqt5, python-import

My aim is to get the user-defined classes only. Try the following things, But  I get all classes. So pls suggest, how to get the user-defined classes only instead of all classes. In my case, iterates/loops approx 200 times for each file( I need only the first three items class A, Class B and Class C only). How to  get the user-defined classes only.

**File : identify_user_defined_class**

```
import importlib
import inspect

file_list =["identify_user_defined_class_base"]
list_class =[]
dict_class = {}

aa = 0

for items in file_list:
    module_name = importlib.import_module(items)

    for class_name,class_obj in inspect.getmembers(module_name):
        aa = aa+1
        print("bbbbb", aa,class_name,class_obj)
        if inspect.isclass(class_obj) and str(class_obj)[0:12] != "<class 'PyQt":
            source, start_line = inspect.getsourcelines(class_obj)
            list_class.append([start_line,class_name])
            dict_class.update({class_name:class_obj})
    list_class.sort()
```

**File : identify_user_defined_class_base**

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class A(QWidget):
    pass

class B(QWidget):
    pass

class C(QWidget):
    pass
```

Comment: What is a "user-defined class"? If you write a module yourself and import it, is it user-defined? What if you publish that module in a package on PyPI? Still user-defined? If so, what classes are not user-defined? Only ones that are part the Python standard library? Or do you only want classes that were defined in the same module where you're trying to find them? (in which case: what's the point, you already know, they're right there)

Comment: Adding even more to what written above, if what you're trying to attempt is to get "subclasses", then your assumption is just wrong, considering the fact that *all* classes are actually subclasses of the base object type. If you want to find all subclasses that *directly* inherit from a specific class, then just check the classes `__mro__`. Still, it's unclear what you would need this for. I'm under the impression that you're just asking the wrong question (see [XY problem](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)), so please explain what you're trying to do and why.

Comment: @musicamante, I want to get only a particular file/module subclasses only.Not all modules . for example I get only a subclasses for "identify_user_defined_class_base" modules.

Comment: @Bala and what about the *why*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple solution is to compare the [`__module__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#index-48) attribute of the class with the name of the imported module. This attribute specifies the module in which the class is defined, so it is sufficient to distinguish it from all other imported or built-in classes.

Thus, in your example, you can simply do:

```
if inspect.isclass(class_obj) and class_obj.__module__ == items:
    ...
```

However, although this might be good enough for your immediate use-case, it isn't a particularly robust solution. One obvious problem with it, is that it doesn't handle sub-classes very well. For example, consider a module like this:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget

class BaseClass(QWidget):
    def commomMethod(self):
        ...

class ClassA(BaseClass):
    ...

class ClassB(ClassA):
    ...
```

For your use-case, I presume you would want to include `ClassA` and `ClassB`, but ***not*** `BaseClass`. However, not allowing this very common form of subclassing would probably be too restrictive for a system like this. So the usual solution is to define a special base-class that explicitly marks the classes you want to import. This would mean the above module would look like this:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget
from mymodule import MarkerClass

class BaseClass(QWidget): ...
class ClassA(BaseClass, MarkerClass): ...
class ClassB(ClassA): ...
```

And your importer code would then look like this:

```
from mymodule import MarkerClass
...

if (inspect.isclass(class_obj) and class_obj is not MarkerClass and
    issubclass(class_obj, MarkerClass)):
    ...
```

where `MarkerClass` can just be an empty class definition, like this:

```
class MarkerClass: pass
```

This approach will be much more robust and easier to maintain in the long-run, and allows for much greater flexibility when designing the dynamically imported classes.

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
for items in file_list:
    module_name = importlib.import_module(items)
    dict_class.update([class_item for class_item in inspect.getmembers(module_name, inspect.isclass) if class_item[1].__module__ == items])
```